# Name-calling and hostile comments

Tags: discussion

I am a bit confused, did I say something wrong?

[A little while ago this question was posted and closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30905631/is-adobe-air-still-actively-supported) because it is off-topic. It's about the support of the AIR runtime on mobile devices. I attempted to answer the question in a comment, but the OP responded to me rudely.

My questions:

1. Does my comment come off as hostile or rude?
2. How should you deal with behavior such as name-calling?

I mean sure, everyone can have a bad day, but isn't this a bit uncalled for?

Edit: The question has been removed by the moderation staff, which effectively ends this discussion. Thanks for the answers and comments, next time I will flag&ignore comments such as that.

Comment: Yes, seems he's having a bad day (or is generally a jerk; I don't know him so I can't say.) You can flag his comments; then just walk away. It's not worth getting into quarrels like that, all they do is drain energy.

Comment: Snark is powerless against help vampires, you'll get bitten anyway. Just stop feeding them.

Answer (score 11):

1. Does my comment come off as hostile or rude?

No.

2. How should you deal with behaviour such as name-calling?

Flag when you feel it's necessary and is covered by the standard flag options, ignore otherwise. If the user goes on a rampage against you, make it a custom flag. However, this is not warranted in your situation.

Don't make too big a deal out of it though. There will always be people around who misinterpret your intentions. Give it your best, see what happens and don't worry.

Comment: I see, I didn't even consider flagging comments. Making a big deal out of it isn't my intention, I was just surprised by his reaction.

Comment: Hey, did SO fix lists starting at numbers other than `1.`? Nice...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Partially, and months ago. It must be a positive whole number...

Answer (score 2):

People like to take their imaginary internet points personally. I too would be a little bummed—and might lash out—if my question got 8 down votes and was closed as off-topic. However, that user has almost 3k reputation. He should know by now that such a question is off-topic.

To answer your questions, your comments are neither rude nor uncalled for and you should deal with such behavior by flagging the comments and moving on. You have better things to do than to quarrel (I presume).

Comment: "You have better things to do than to quarrel" - https://xkcd.com/386/

Answer (score 2):

1. Does my comment come off as hostile or rude?

A little bit. I don't know whether you meant the comment in a malicious way. Only you would know that, so if you are honest with yourself you will be able to figure it out.

However, for your interest, here is how I could read your comment as having a malicious tone. Note that I'm not trying to be hostile or rude here =P.

A few things stand out in it which gives it a negative tone: the "like" in "like 1 week ago", the "Doesn't that suffice ...?", and the "I doubt anyone on SO is clairvoyant ..." prefacing the "we don't know how much longer it'll be supported" line.

Together it paints a picture of a post which I can infer as being hostile, or at least condescending. The "like" indicates it's a throwaway comment, like you couldn't even be bothered to check because it's so obvious anyway. The "Doesn't that suffice..." phrasing gives it an air of incredulity, like it clearly should suffice and the other is perhaps foolish for not recognizing so. And finally the "I doubt anyone on SO is clairvoyant..." preface is a bit snarky. After all, nobody thinks people on SO are clairvoyant, only a fool would do so, and to bring it up means the poster may have been expecting people to do so.

Again only you will know whether it was meant to be hostile or rude. But maybe the above will help, as an insight into how some people (at least one person, me) might read it.

Comment: I see, I will consider this for my future comments and answers. Thank you for your detailed answer.

Comment: @DodgerThud - I would like to also point out, in addition to what Claudiu said, that differences in the level of English knowledge and culture can make the different from "little rude" to "I want to punch this guy". Sometimes when they teach you English (not natively) they explain you that certain words have certain meaning, but many times Natives not necessarily use or prefer that meaning. I don't know if it applies to this case since I can't see the original question, but I have seen it happen other times.